# lavaan suddenly not analyzing ordered factors correctly?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

SOLVED: So thought I'd share. The single indicator variables have to be numeric, can't be factor. In the first run I had converted them to integer in order to get their variance, for the error variance input, and didn't realize I had left them that way but was trying to keep them factor for the new run.

I've been running SEMs the last few days in lavaan, but now want to go through my final model building procedure and lavaan is now switching between not converging and saying that some of my estimated ov's have negative variances, depending which model I try to run. Pretty sure this started when I messed up something in my data frame and had to re-upload it and reprocess it, but I didn't do anything differently, used the exact same syntax as before! I looked at the variances of my variables, but the factors show as NA, and I'm not sure how to learn more about lavaan's estimation of OV thresholds which I guess would be the problem here. My saved outputs from yesterday confirm the syntax and software version are the same.

Details:
My model fit is great (robust CFI .982-.999 depending on model, other stats good too), my data frame says that the variables in question are ordered factors with the correct number of levels when I inspect them, and if I run a numeric version of the dataset with the same WLSMV estimator it runs fine (but produces different estimators since it treats the ordinal vars as continuous, so I don't want to do this). Same with std.lv, technically runs better but that doesn't work with my single indicator situation.

Possible sources of problems: It's possibly related somehow to the single indicators I'm using since their estimates are completely wrong when the model does run (but others/measurement are reasonable), but again I haven't changed anything about their treatment or coding (giving each an lv with loading set to 1, .1 error variance on indicator). I also have several standardized vars, one with a negative mean because it was from a Rasch model (logit), but again, none of this has changed at all.

I really don't know what has changed in the last 24 hours/ when I re-uploaded and reprocessed my data set! I'm somewhat desperate for help on this!

Example of input and 2 different outputs:

```
> #M0: Simple causal
> Model0 <- '#Measurement
+ RiskPercep =~ WhenHarm + Worry + HarmYou + HarmComm + HarmUS + HarmDev
+ STEMExp =~ STEMRec + STEMClass
+ Belief =~ 1*CCBelief
+ Politics =~ 1*Liberal
+ 
+ #fixing error
+ CCBelief ~~ .092*CCBelief
+ Liberal ~~ .095*Liberal
+ 
+ #regression
+ RiskPercep ~ Belief + CIScore + Politics
+ CIScore ~ STEMExp
+ Belief ~ CIScore + Politics'
> Model0Fit <- sem(Model0, data=ClimateSurveyImp)
summary(Model0Fit, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE)
----------
> Model9Fit <- sem(Model9, data=ClimateSurveyImp)
Warning message:
In lav_object_post_check(object) :
  lavaan WARNING: some estimated ov variances are negative

> Model0Fit <- sem(Model0, data=ClimateSurveyImp)
Warning message:
In lavaan::lavaan(model = Model0, data = FinalData, model.type = "sem",  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    the optimizer warns that a solution has NOT been found!
> summary(Model0Fit, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE, rsquare=TRUE)
lavaan 0.6-11 did NOT end normally after 2542 iterations
** WARNING ** Estimates below are most likely unreliable
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting R?

Comment: Yes, a couple of times (also, if anyone is wondering, n=675 and no missing values)